# Unexpected effect of type annotation on class members

Tags: python, class, annotations, type-hinting, python-typing

```py
class X:
    a: str
```

Both `X.a` and `X().a` give `AttributeError`. Defining without type-annotation `: str` gives `NameError`. How is python interpreting `a: str`? Real-world example at [fastapi docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body-fields/#__code_1) (look for `name: str`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotating an uninitialized variable is fine, but all it does is it creates an `__annotations__` dictionary in the class `X` and adds to it an entry recording the annotation: `X.__annotations__` becomes `{'a': str}`. This by itself does not create an attribute of the class `X` that can be referenced, since there is no value corresponding to `a`.